# Bash - Hardware Info (Spanish text in the script)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

```
#!/bin/bash

function Procesador()
{ 

# Determinando la Velocidad del Procesador
CPUMHz=`cat /var/log/dmesg | grep "MHz processor" | cut -d " " -f07 | sed 's/[.].*//'`
if [ "$CPUMHz" -ge "133" ];
    then
        if [ "$CPUMHz" -ge "1032" ];
        then        
        let "CPUGHz"=$CPUMHz/1000
            echo "$CPUGHz GHz"
        else
            echo "$CPUMHz Mhz"
        fi
    else
        echo "Menos de 133 Mhz de Procesador"
fi


}

function MemoriaRAM()
{ 

# Determinando la Cantidad De memoria RAM
RAM_Kb=`grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'`
    if [[ "$RAM_Kb" -lt "1048576" ]];
        then
            let RAM_MB=$RAM_Kb/1024
            echo "$RAM_MB MB"
        elif [[ "$RAM_Kb" -gt "1048576" ]];
        then
            let "RAMGb"=$RAM_Kb/1024
            RAMGb=`echo "scale=1; 1*($RAM_Kb/1024000)" | bc -l`
            echo "$RAMGb" "GB"
    else
    echo "Menos de 16 MB RAM"
fi

}

function Video() 
{
# Determinando Tarjeta De Video
# Determinando Memoria De Video
vcard=`lspci -v | grep "VGA" | cut -d " " -f05`
MDV=`MB_DE_VIDEO`
echo "$MDV"
}

function MB_DE_VIDEO()
{
# Determinando Memoria De Video
vcard=$(lspci -v | grep "VGA" | cut -d " " -f05)
vidsize=$(lspci -v -s `lspci | awk '/VGA/{print $1}'` | sed -n '/Memory.*, prefetchable/s/.*\[size=\([^]]\+\)M\]/\1/p')
Conviduso=$(lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use' | cut -d " " -f05)
    if [ "$vidsize" -ge "8" ]
        then
            echo "Tarjeta De Video : $vcard "
            echo "Memoria De Video : $vidsize MB"

            if [ "$Conviduso" = "" ]; then
                    echo "Control De Video : Desconocido"
            fi
            if [ "$Conviduso" = "nvidia" ]; then
                    echo "Control De Video : $Conviduso (Privativo)"
            fi

            if [ "$Conviduso" = "nv" ]; then
                    echo "Control De Video : $Conviduso (Libre)"
            fi

            if [ "$Conviduso" = "nouveau" ]; then
                    echo "Control De Video : $Conviduso (Libre)"
            fi

            if [ "$Conviduso" = "radeon" ]; then
                    echo "Control De Video : $Conviduso (Libre)"
            fi

            if [ "$Conviduso" = "fglrx" ]; then
                    echo "Control De Video : $Conviduso (Privativo)"
            fi

            if [ "$Conviduso" = "fglrx_pci" ]; then
                    echo "Control De Video : $Conviduso (Privativo)"
            fi

            if [ "$Conviduso" = "openchrome" ]; then
                    echo "Control De Video : $Conviduso (Libre)"
            fi

            if [ "$Conviduso" = "intel" ]; then
                    echo "Control De Video : $Conviduso (Libre)"
            fi

                support3d=$(glxinfo | grep "direct rendering: Yes" | cut -d " " -f03)
                if [ $support3d = "Yes" ];
                    then
                        echo "Funcion De Video : Soporte 3D & Renderizado Directo"
                    else
                        echo "Funcion De Video : Sin Soporte 3D"
                fi
        else
            echo "Menos de 8 MB de Video y sin Soporte 3D"
    fi
}


function Arquitectura() 
{

# Determinando la Arquitectura de la Maquina
arch=`uname -m`
if        [ $arch = "i386" ]; then
            echo "Sistema de 32 Bits / x86 "
    elif  [ $arch = "i486" ]; then
            echo "Sistema de 32 Bits / x86 "
    elif  [ $arch = "i586" ]; then
            echo "Sistema de 32 Bits / x86 "
    elif  [ $arch = "i686" ]; then
            echo "Sistema de 32 Bits / x86 "
    elif  [ $arch = "x86_64" ]; then
            echo "Sistema de 64 Bits / x86_64 "
    else
        echo "Architectura Desconocida"
fi


}

function CPUCache()
{

# Determinando la Cache del CPU
CpuCache=`awk -F':' '/^cache size/ { print $2 }' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | cut -d " " -f02`
if [ "$CpuCache" -ge "1024" ]
    then
        if [ "$CpuCache" -ge "1024" ]
        then
        let "CpuCacheMB"=$CpuCache/1000
            echo "$CpuCacheMB MB"
        else
        let "CpuCacheKB"=$CpuCache/1000
            echo "$CpuCacheKB Kb"
        fi
    else
    echo "Menos de 256 KB de Cache"
fi

}

clear
echo '#########################################################################'
echo '####      Script de Inukaze para Información del PC        ####'
echo '#########################################################################'
echo ""
VDP=`Procesador`
echo "Tienes : `grep -c 'processor' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq` Procesador(es)"
echo "La Velocidad de la CPU es : $VDP "
CCache=`CPUCache`
echo "El Tamaño de Cache de la CPU es: $CCache"
echo "La Compañía de la CPU es :`awk -F':' '/^vendor_id/ { print $2 }' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq`"
ARCH=`Arquitectura`
echo "La Arquitectura Utilizada es: $ARCH " 
echo "Módelo del CPU :`awk -F':' '/^model name/ { print $2 }' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq`"
echo ""
echo "#########################################################################"
echo "####      Información de la Memoria & Video            ####"
echo "#########################################################################"
echo ""
MRAM=`MemoriaRAM`
echo "Memoria RAM : $MRAM "
echo ""
MVID=`Video`
echo "$MVID "
echo ""
echo "#########################################################################"

XORG=$(ps -A|grep Xorg|awk '{print $4}')
XFREE86=$(ps -A|grep XFree86|awk '{print $4}')

if [ "$XORG" = "Xorg" ]; then
if [ -f "$HOME"/.infohw ]; then
 rm -rf "$HOME"/.infohw
fi
echo '#########################################################################' >> $HOME/.infohw
echo '####      Script de Inukaze para Informacion del PC        ####' >> $HOME/.infohw
echo '#########################################################################' >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "" >> $HOME/.infohw
VDP=`Procesador`
echo "Tienes : `grep -c 'processor' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq` Procesador(es)" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "La Velocidad de la CPU es : $VDP " >> $HOME/.infohw
CCache=`CPUCache`
echo "El Tamano de Cache de la CPU es: $CCache" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "La Compania de la CPU es :`awk -F':' '/^vendor_id/ { print $2 }' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq`" >> $HOME/.infohw
ARCH=`Arquitectura`
echo "La Arquitectura Utilizada es: $ARCH " >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "Modelo del CPU :`awk -F':' '/^model name/ { print $2 }' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq`" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "#########################################################################" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "####      Informacion de la Memoria & Video            ####" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "#########################################################################" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "" >> $HOME/.infohw
MRAM=`MemoriaRAM`
echo "Memoria RAM : $MRAM " >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "" >> $HOME/.infohw
MVID=`Video`
echo "$MVID " >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "#########################################################################" >> $HOME/.infohw
xmessage -file "$HOME/.infohw"
fi

if [ "$XFREE86" = "XFree86" ]; then
if [ -f "$HOME"/.infohw ]; then
 rm -rf "$HOME"/.infohw
fi
echo '#########################################################################' >> $HOME/.infohw
echo '####      Script de Inukaze para Informacion del PC        ####' >> $HOME/.infohw
echo '#########################################################################' >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "" >> $HOME/.infohw
VDP=`Procesador`
echo "Tienes : `grep -c 'processor' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq` Procesador(es)" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "La Velocidad de la CPU es : $VDP " >> $HOME/.infohw
CCache=`CPUCache`
echo "El Tamano de Cache de la CPU es: $CCache" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "La Compania de la CPU es :`awk -F':' '/^vendor_id/ { print $2 }' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq`" >> $HOME/.infohw
ARCH=`Arquitectura`
echo "La Arquitectura Utilizada es: $ARCH " >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "Modelo del CPU :`awk -F':' '/^model name/ { print $2 }' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq`" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "#########################################################################" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "####      Informacion de la Memoria & Video            ####" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "#########################################################################" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "" >> $HOME/.infohw
MRAM=`MemoriaRAM`
echo "Memoria RAM : $MRAM " >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "" >> $HOME/.infohw
MVID=`Video`
echo "$MVID " >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "" >> $HOME/.infohw
echo "#########################################################################" >> $HOME/.infohw
xmessage -file "$HOME/.infohw"

fi
```

Output (Bash - Terminal) :

```
#########################################################################
####        Script de Inukaze para Información del PC        ####
#########################################################################

Tienes : 2 Procesador(es)
La Velocidad de la CPU es : Menos de 133 Mhz de Procesador 
El Tamaño de Cache de la CPU es: 1 MB
La Compañía de la CPU es : AuthenticAMD
La Arquitectura Utilizada es: Sistema de 32 Bits / x86  
Módelo del CPU : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 6000+

#########################################################################
####        Información de la Memoria & Video            ####
#########################################################################

Memoria RAM : 1.5 GB 

Tarjeta De Video : NVIDIA 
Memoria De Video : 256 MB
Control De Video : nvidia (Privativo) # Video Driver In Use
Funcion De Video : Soporte 3D & Renderizado Directo 

#########################################################################
```

I need help with the parts :

"Control de Video" : The Driver in use during this session (Video Driver)

"La Velocidad de la CPU es" : i need another thing , can read by any user , to get the real total speed of processor(s)

NOTE : if you recieved a error message about "/var/log/dmesg" , you need permissions
you can make it in the terminal with "sudo chmod a+o+rw+x /var/log/dmesg".
i need another thing can not need modify the file system.

I really , want this script , work in every distro , correctly
Im Using Linux Mint 13 MAYA.

Someone can help me with my script ?

Comment: A quick comment: your line `cat /var/log/dmesg | grep "MHz processor"` is a wonderful useless use of `cat`. I didn't even look further in your script `:)`. No offense, but your `bash` style is terrible `:D` and I hope this will never be used in production `:D`.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
if [ "$RAM_Kb" -ge "1024" ];
    then
        let RAM_MB=$RAM_Kb/1024
        echo "$RAM_MB MB"
    elif [ "$RAM_Kb" -gt "102400" ];
    then
        let "RAMGb"=$RAM_Kb/102400  #/8
        RAMGb=`echo "scale=1; 1*($RAM_Kb/1024000)" | bc -l`
        echo "$RAMGb" "GB"
    fi
```

try

```
if [ "$RAM_Kb" -gt "102400" ]
then
    let "RAMGb"=$RAM_Kb/102400  #/8
    RAMGb=`echo "scale=1; 1*($RAM_Kb/1024000)" | bc -l`
    echo "$RAMGb" "GB"
elif [ "$RAM_Kb" -ge "1024" ];;
then
    let RAM_MB=$RAM_Kb/1024
    echo "$RAM_MB MB"

 fi
```

since a GB is Always greater than a MB and you will never reach the else branch.

Comment: Ok the problem its , when if you get a value < 1024 in the "$RAM_Kb" variable , for example , when i try to force to "512" , in the output 

RAM_Kb=512
"Memoria RAM : Menos de 16 MB RAM" ( less 16 MB RAM ) , insted of "512 MB" . that is the problem in the script.

Comment: Thats what you programmed: `if [ "$RAM_Kb" -ge "16000" ];` will go to `else
    echo "Menos de 16 MB RAM"` for all below 16000 (which 512 obviously is)